# Auto-highlight an input field on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering if there was a way for text inside a input box (pre loaded using value="") to highlight when the user clicks on it?

```
input type='text' name='url' id='url' value='http://www.a-link.com/' />
```

*EDIT*

I need the text to he highlighted so the user can copy it.

Comment: ..and for input type="number"?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="textbox" value="Test" onclick="this.select()" />
```

Comment: 1) If you bind it to `onfocus` instead of `onclick` then it will work for keyboard navigation as well as mouse clicks. 2) You can also access the input field from the emitted event object instead of from `this`. E.g. for react you can do `<input onFocus={e => e.target.select()} />`

Comment: Great answer, including the onfocus suggestion.  I found a number of other suggestions, though all of them required JavaScript.

Answer (score 17):

You could attach javascript to the click event to select the text like so:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#id').click( function( event_details ) {
    $(this).select();
  });
});
```

There is a potential issue where the user could be trying to click at a later point in the text to correct a typing mistake and end up selecting the whole thing. A better way would be to trigger this when the input gets focus from the user. you'd replace `.click` with `.focus` in the example above.

jQuery event documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Comment: This is similar to the top answer, but done unobtrusively, which is considered to be more proper.

Answer (score 15):

Add the following `onclick` attribute to make the entire `<input>` automatically highlight when the user clicks on it:

```
<input type="text" value="Test1" onclick="this.select()" />
```

Alternatively, if you want the user to be able to change the selection after the initial click, change the onclick attribute to an `onfocus` attribute. This will also highlight the entire `<input>` when the user clicks on it, but it allows them to change the highlighted part manually afterwards:

```
<input type="text" value="Test2" onfocus="this.select()" />
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/WK_of_Angmar/pEyeE/) is an example of both inputs in action.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use focus property. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/sCuNs/

html

```
  <p><input type="text" size="40"></p>
```

css

```
input:focus, textarea:focus{
background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need the text to he highlighted so the user can copy it.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean to select the text?

Use `onclick` event to fire the code:

```
document.getElementById("target-input-id").select();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#foo').on('mouseup', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).select();
});

$('#foo').on('mouseup', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).select();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
<input type='text' name='url' id='url' onclick="this.select()" value='http://www.a-link.com/' />
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<input id="inputField" type="text" size="40" value="text to be highlighted"></p>
    
document.getElementById('inputField').focus();
```

The default behavior for focus selects the text in the input field. I was looking for a solution not to do that when I found this.